Gradle version compatibility query
Looking at:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html
What problem would there be (if any) in using Gradle 8.7 with Java 21, the compatibility matrix in the link above looks like Gradle 8.7 only works with Java 22?

It's the opposite. New Gradle versions are backwards compatible with Java versions going back to Java 8 (docs).
So no problem at all running the latest Gradle on Java 21 (true for version 8.4 onwards to be precise). Just don't expect it to run yet with Java 22 (though you can use Java 22 as a "toolchain", ie for compiling and running your code).
